# Adding space after paragraphs affects references

Tags: spacing

I am using the following command in order to have an empty line after each paragraph.

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
```

However, by doing so, the references generated with bibtex also get some spaces which I do not want and which disappear if I remove the code above.

Is there any way of removing that space? Also, is there any way of removing the spacing before a chosen paragraph?

Comment: you might like the `parskip` package

Comment: Noob here. How do I use it?

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}` and then comment out the two lines you've posted from your document

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thank you. Do you happen to know how I can slightly increase the spacing between the paragraphs as well?

Comment: `\setlength\parskip{1.2\baselineskip}` for instance. Beware this will also affect lists — and many latex environments have  an underlying list structure.